# how to set different prices to a magento configurable product in assoiciated product?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, associate-products

i am new to magento and i have referred too much magento tutorials for configurable product with associated product and super attribute but still my issue is not fixed,so i have asked this question.please i need help.

i wants to make a configurable product like,
tshirts having 2 attributes as color and size,
tshirt product with $20 with size 28,30,32 having color red,green,blue but i wants to make different price for only one associated product tshirt with size 30 having color blue as $25(+ $5 more than any other combinations). how can i do this??

i have created all combinations of associated products for attribute color and size and i have also change the price of that assoiciated product tshirt size-30 having color-blue as $25 but it not showing in store it shows price of configueable product. please help...

Answer (score 1):

Magento by default takes configurable products price. What you can do is goto Associated product, their you will see all combinations of color and size. Leave everything blank except for size 30 and color blue, in this text box only write 5 and you are done.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but where is such textbox ?

let me show the issue,
associated products configuration screensnap link http://prnt.sc/b3uv4o
store view screensnap link http://prnt.sc/b3uw8x

Comment: Please anybody help me i have given link of screenshots... Plzz

Comment: http://prnt.sc/b3uv4o write 5 ahead of option size 30 and color blue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,i have tried that too but it changes the price for whole blue color variations while i just wants to change for only one blue color having size 30 only to this associated product with +$5 more,not to whole blue color's associated products.

Answer (score 1):

We achieved this in Magento 1.9 by editting

> Admin Panel>Catalog>Manage Products>Your Configurable
>   Product>Associated Products>Super product attributes configuration
>   --->

Edit the price field for each desired option by either adding or subtracting values from base price. In our example kids sizes are cheaper so we type in -5 in kids sizes. I don't know weather thats the correct way of doing it, but it seems to work for us.

Comment: may be all are have different views for this problem. i think installing extension is more better for this.

Answer (score 0):

Open associated products of that configurable products. And select price field from left sidebar. Update the price and click on save and continue.
Thats it.